# Multiple tests to multiple objects

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, jestjs

I have create test class and test cases for it:

```js
class SimpleApp extends React.Component {
}

describe("test simple app", function() {
  it("must render like...", function() {
    const wrapper = mount(<SimpleApp/>);
  }
}
```

Now I create different class which must pass same test set together with previous.

```js
class SimpleApp extends React.Component {
}

class AdvancedApp extends React.Component {
}

...
```

Please suggest solution how to test both class with same test set and minimal code duplication.

Comment: Is that a homework ?

Comment: No, there is not of course. I'd like to know is there special tools for that. I have provided possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had thinking that the test framework have some special tools for this case like `before` or `beforeAll`. If such tool exists please let me know by creation the answer. If there is no such tools this may be the answer:

```js
class SimpleApp extends React.Component {
}

class AdvancedApp extends React.Component {
}

[SimpleApp, AdvancedApp].forEach( App => {
  describe("test simple app", function() {
    it("must render like...", function() {
      const wrapper = mount(<App/>);
    }
  }
})
```